# Consuming java web service from .NET client

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to consume a java web service from .NET. 
When I add service reference to generate proxy and run the programme i get the error below

> The formatter threw an exception while
>   trying to deserialize the message:
>   There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter
>   http://order.x.service.y.com:requestPayment.

Apparently I have to tweak the proxy classes generated  bacause of differences in namespaces between JAVA and .NET but am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the java web service has at least some non-interoperable features.

Do you have access to the java web service code?  If so, maybe you can create your own proxy class that can talk with it.  I would not try to change the auto-generated proxy code.  I'd suggest hooking up to the java web service manually instead of by adding a Service Reference.

Although this [article](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=0809101) is geared mainly to consuming WCF services, it goes into some depth in consuming services manually. You'll be able to follow most of the steps for manual proxy connection even though you're pointing to a java service.